# Shell script to stop a java program

Tags: java, shell, ksh

Is there a way to stop a java program running using a shell script by knowing the name alone.I am using ksh shell

Comment: Knowing what name? If you know the name of the executable (which normally is `java` though), `killall` is your friend.

Comment: @sfussenegger: Probably he doesn't want to kill all java-processes, but only one specific.

Comment: @Mnementh that's what I'd expect too, but from the given information this is the best thing I could recommend.

Comment: you might also want to look at start-stop-daemon if the process you're trying to kill is meant to run as a daemon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a unique property to the JVM to identify it easily, e.g. for test.class

```
java -Duniquename=1 test
```

To kill it:

```
ps ax | grep uniquename | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Comment: It works fine under KSH. Maybe you've made an error copying the command.

Comment: 'grep [u]niquename' is an alternative to 'grep uniquename | grep -v grep'

Answer (score 20):

following up on [Mnementh' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131874/shell-script-to-stop-a-java-program/2131894#2131894):

this should do the job

```
jps -l | grep org.example.MyMain | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs -rn1 kill
```

- `jps -l`: list java process with "full package name for the application's main class or the full path name  to  the  application's  JAR file."
- `grep`: choose the process you like
- `cut -d -' ' -f 1`: split the output in columns using delimiter ' ' and print only the first one (the pid)
- `xargs -rn1 kill`: execute kill for each PID (if any)

note that you must run jps and xargs with the same user (or root) as you're running the process

Comment: This will also work for windows machines, but you're going to need to do some environment detection to figure out which `kill` to use.

Comment: @Odelya I've just added `-r` (`--no-run-if-empty`) to `xargs` to avoid this error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jps identifying the process-id associated with the name of the started java-program (jps is a process-manager for java-programs). With this id you can kill the process normally.

Comment: assuming my java file name is test.java and is running how to find it?

Comment: @Harish: After compiling it and executing it will be shown as 'test'. If you package it in an executable jar (test.jar) and execute via 'java -jar test.jar' jps shows 'test.jar'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pkill:

```
pkill your_java_program_name
```

This would work if you run only one instance of the your program is running.

Answer (score 1):

you can use -o option of ps to format your output,

```
ps -eo cmd,pid | awk '!/awk/&&/mycommand/{cmd="kill -9 "$2;system(cmd)}'
```